# For comprehension Dynamic List of Futures : Scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use for comprehension to execute list of futures in series. The output of one future becomes input of the next future. Below is the sample code.

```
for {
      x <- plugins(0).execute(input)
      y <- plugins(1).execute(x)
      z <- plugins(2).excute(y)
    } yield z
```

The above code acts more like a waterfall, each plugins(i) executes on some input, and passes the output to next plugin. The output of the last plugin is the final output.
plugins is a Seq of Plugin object. The execute method returns a Future. I want to make the above code more generic, where the number of plugin in Plugins is dynamic. How do i go about implementing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
plugins.foldLeft(Future.successful(input)) { (resultFuture, plugin) =>     
  resultFuture.flatMap(plugin.execute(_))
}
```

There are two tools in use here: [`foldLeft`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foldLeft[B](z:B)(f:(B,A)=%3EB):B) and [`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S](f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S])

Take a look at these links, and see if you understand what those functions do

`Future.successful` just wraps input into a Future, so that we can treat it the same way we do all the other intermediate results. Underscore is a shortcut for the lambda function parameter. Another way to write that piece would be: `resultFuture.flatMap { result => plugin.execute(result) }`.

Comment: can you explain how the above code works, i am still trying to figure my way around scala. thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? 
There are two tools in use here: `foldLeft` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foldLeft[B](z:B)(f:(B,A)=>B):B and `flatMap` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S](f:T=>scala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]. Take a look at these links, and see if you understand what those functions do.

Comment: why do we need Future.successful, and what is the underscore?

Comment: `Future.successful` just wraps `input` into a `Future`, so that we can treat it the same way we do all the other intermediate results. Underscore is a shortcut for the lambda function parameter. Another way to write that piece would be: `resultFuture.flatMap { result => plugin.execute(result) }.

Comment: Who are the idiots voting this down? Are you guys having a bad night? Can I help you with something?

Comment: Nor sure why you mention Future.successful, but i see no reason for a vote down

Comment: @pedrofurla l explained the need for `Future.successful` in a comment above. Or, are you asking why I mentioned it in the comment? :) That would be because I was asked about it earlier :) As to why it appears in the text of the answer, it looks like someone edited it, and copied my comments there. I guess, they thought it was important enough to be mentioned there. I don't think so, but whatever.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was wondering why it was in the answer. The down votes still puzzles me.